# Javascript function not working as externel file

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

When I include the following js function as an external file it simple doesn't work but it works fine when I add it in my html page in script tags. Someone told me to save the file in UTF-8 encoding fr it to work but it still not working. What could be the issue? The point to be noted is that all other external js files work fine.

**JS file:**

```
 function update_status(val)
    {
        var order_status = val.options[val.selectedIndex].value;
        var order_id = val.id;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "<?php echo site_url('Canteen_management/update_status'); ?>";
        var vars = "order_id="+order_id+"&order_status="+order_status;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.send(vars); 
    }
```

Included at the bottom of the body tag of the html page like this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/update_order_status_all.js');?>"></script>
```

Comment: Did you call the function somewhere?

Comment: unless you told your webserver that .js files are to be treated as php scripts, the php code in there will **NOT** be executed. the php code go will go out as plain text, and you're telling the client browser that the url to use literally starts with the characters `<`, `?`, `p`, etc...

Comment: "simply does not work" is pretty much the worst error description. Have you checked if any errors appear in the developer console of your favourite browser?

Comment: You have PHP code in the js file. When you include it using the `<script>` tags it is not going to run that internal PHP code. It will however CRASH the js code in the browser which you should have been able to see if you looked that the browsers js debugger

Comment: Consider these. 1. `index.php` removed from URL call. 2. Jquery Library loaded. 3. Your JS file loaded.

Comment: RiggsFolly, your solution worked. I removed the php code from the js external file and it worked. Thanks.